# Fastest way to replace NAs in a large data.table

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, data.table

I have a large [data.table](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html), with many missing values scattered throughout its ~200k rows and 200 columns.  I would like to re code those NA values to zeros as efficiently as possible.

I see two options:
1: Convert to a data.frame, and use something [like this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-replace-all-lt-NA-gt-values-in-a-data-frame-with-another-not-0-value-td2125458.html)
2: Some kind of cool data.table sub setting command

I'll be happy with a fairly efficient solution of type 1. Converting to a data.frame and then back to a data.table won't take too long.

Comment: Why do you want to convert the `data.table` to a `data.frame`?  A `data.table` **is** a `data.frame`.  Any data.frame operation will just work.

Comment: @Andrie. a key difference is that you cant access a column in a `data.table` by specifying column number. so `DT[,3]` will not give the third column. i think this makes the solution proposed in the link unviable here. i am sure there is an elegant approach using some `data.table` wizardry!

Comment: @Ramnath: you're exactly right!  At the moment, I'm converting to a data.frame and looping through the columns to replace the NAs, but I'm looking for some elegant data.table wizardry!

Comment: @Zach. what function are you exactly going to be applying on the data table. it might be fine retaining the NAs and dealing with them later. if you provide more details, i think it would be easier to come up with a `data.table` solution.

Comment: @Ramnath: The situation is that the data table is the result of a large aggregation and merging operation.  The values in most of the columns are counts, and the NAs are in fact zeros (no counts=no observations).  I need to recode these NAs as zeros because I am going to be building a predictive model using this dataset.

Comment: @Ramnath, AFAIK, `DT[, 3, with=FALSE]` returns the third column.

Comment: @Andrie. good point. i completely forgot about the `with` argument.

Comment: @Andrie. but there is still a problem `mydf[is.na(mydf) == TRUE]` does the job on data frames, while `mydt[is.na(mydt) == TRUE]` gives me something strange even if i use `with=FALSE`

Comment: @Ramnath, point taken.  My earlier statement was too broad, i.e. I was wrong.  Sorry.  Data.tables only behave like data.frames when there isn't a data.table method.

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Here's a solution using [data.table](http://r-datatable.com)'s `:=` operator, building on Andrie and Ramnath's answers.

```
require(data.table)  # v1.6.6
require(gdata)       # v2.8.2

set.seed(1)
dt1 = create_dt(2e5, 200, 0.1)
dim(dt1)
[1] 200000    200    # more columns than Ramnath's answer which had 5 not 200

f_andrie = function(dt) remove_na(dt)

f_gdata = function(dt, un = 0) gdata::NAToUnknown(dt, un)

f_dowle = function(dt) {     # see EDIT later for more elegant solution
  na.replace = function(v,value=0) { v[is.na(v)] = value; v }
  for (i in names(dt))
    eval(parse(text=paste("dt[,",i,":=na.replace(",i,")]")))
}

system.time(a_gdata = f_gdata(dt1)) 
   user  system elapsed 
 18.805  12.301 134.985 

system.time(a_andrie = f_andrie(dt1))
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 305.2 Mb
Timing stopped at: 14.541 7.764 68.285 

system.time(f_dowle(dt1))
  user  system elapsed 
 7.452   4.144  19.590     # EDIT has faster than this

identical(a_gdata, dt1)   
[1] TRUE
```

Note that f_dowle updated dt1 by reference. If a local copy is required then an explicit call to the `copy` function is needed to make a local copy of the whole dataset. data.table's `setkey`, `key<-` and `:=` do not copy-on-write.

Next, let's see where f_dowle is spending its time.

```
Rprof()
f_dowle(dt1)
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof()
$by.self
                  self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
"na.replace"           5.10    49.71       6.62     64.52
"[.data.table"         2.48    24.17       9.86     96.10
"is.na"                1.52    14.81       1.52     14.81
"gc"                   0.22     2.14       0.22      2.14
"unique"               0.14     1.36       0.16      1.56
... snip ...
```

There, I would focus on `na.replace` and `is.na`, where there are a few vector copies and vector scans. Those can fairly easily be eliminated by writing a small na.replace C function that updates `NA` by reference in the vector. That would at least halve the 20 seconds I think. Does such a function exist in any R package?

The reason `f_andrie` fails may be because it copies the whole of `dt1`, or creates a logical matrix as big as the whole of `dt1`, a few times. The other 2 methods work on one column at a time (although I only briefly looked at `NAToUnknown`).

**EDIT** (more elegant solution as requested by Ramnath in comments) :

```
f_dowle2 = function(DT) {
  for (i in names(DT))
    DT[is.na(get(i)), (i):=0]
}

system.time(f_dowle2(dt1))
  user  system elapsed 
 6.468   0.760   7.250   # faster, too

identical(a_gdata, dt1)   
[1] TRUE
```

I wish I did it that way to start with!

**EDIT2** (over 1 year later, now)

There is also `set()`. This can be faster if there are a lot of column being looped through, as it avoids the (small) overhead of calling `[,:=,]` in a loop. `set` is a loopable `:=`. See `?set`.

```
f_dowle3 = function(DT) {
  # either of the following for loops

  # by name :
  for (j in names(DT))
    set(DT,which(is.na(DT[[j]])),j,0)

  # or by number (slightly faster than by name) :
  for (j in seq_len(ncol(DT)))
    set(DT,which(is.na(DT[[j]])),j,0)
}
```

Comment: +! great answer! is it possible to have a more intuitive equivalent of the  `eval(parse)...` stuff. on a broader note, i think it would be useful to have operations that work on all elements of the `data.table`.

Comment: @Ramnath  See edit: avoids `eval(parse)` and is much faster, too. Yes we could do ops that work on all elements. There is an [open roadmap](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?group_id=240) for data.table - feel free to add feature requests there and that way it won't get forgotten.

Comment: Your 2nd block of code seems to be the most `data.table` appropriate way to do this.  Thanks!

Comment: hmmm, the current version of `data.table` seems to break your most recent function.  Also, `create_dt` no longer exists!

Comment: @Zach Hi. `create_dt` is in Andrie's answer. What's the error? When you say current version, you mean 1.8.2 on CRAN, or 1.8.3 on R-Forge?

Comment: @MatthewDowle: Hmmm, and this morning it's working fine.  I'll have to go back and write a reproducible example, sorry!

Comment: @MattDowle it seems to me that `f_dowle3` was broken again in `data.table_1.9.4`.  I get a complaint from `set()`, `Warning message:
In set(DT, which(is.na(DT[[j]])), j, 0) :
  Coerced 'double' RHS to 'logical' to match the column's type`

Comment: @Statwonk I guess your `DT` has columns of type `logical`, unlike the `create_dt()` example for this test. Change the 4th argument of the `set()` call (which is `0` in your example and type double in R) to `FALSE` and it should work without warning.

Comment: @Statwonk And I've filed a feature request to relax this case and drop that warning when coercing length-1 vectors 0 and 1 to logical: [#996](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/996). Might not do it since, for speed, you do want to be warned about unnecessary  repetitive coercing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's REALLY fast. 6.1mln x 196 data.table got treated in 10 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and all the benchmarking. Tiny nitpick: you can replace `seq_len(ncol(DT))` by `seq_along(DT)`

Comment: @StefanF True and I prefer `seq_along(DT)` too.  But then the reader has to know that `seq_along` would be along the columns and not down the rows.  `seq_len(col(DT))` a tiny bit more explicit for that reason.

Comment: For my data, the answer here seemed much quicker, maybe worth a try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535505/replacing-all-missing-values-in-r-data-table-with-a-value

Comment: @MattDowle I have been trying to adapt your code to take into account column type, and replace negative values with NA's instead of replacing NA's with 0. I have however not been very successful. Would you perhaps be willing to take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52382298/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-replace-values-in-large-datasets

Answer (score 55):

Here's the simplest one I could come up with:

`dt[is.na(dt)] <- 0`

It's efficient and no need to write functions and other glue code.

Comment: doesn't work on big datasets and normal workstation computers (memory allocation error)

Comment: @Jake on a machine with 16GB of RAM I was able to run this on 31M rows, ~20 columns. YMMV of course.

Comment: I defer to your empirical evidence. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunatelly in the latest versions of data.table it doesn't work.  It says Error in `[.data.table`(dt, is.na(dt)) : 
  i is invalid type (matrix). Perhaps in future a 2 column matrix could return a list of elements of DT (in the spirit of A[B] in FAQ 2.14). Please let datatable-help know if you'd like this, or add your comments to FR #657.
>

Comment: this is interesting! I always used `set`

Answer (score 34):

Dedicated functions (`nafill` and `setnafill`) for that purpose are available in `data.table` package (version >= 1.12.4):

It process columns in parallel so well address previously posted benchmarks, below its timings vs fastest approach till now, and also scaled up, using 40 cores machine.

```r
library(data.table)
create_dt <- function(nrow=5, ncol=5, propNA = 0.5){
  v <- runif(nrow * ncol)
  v[sample(seq_len(nrow*ncol), propNA * nrow*ncol)] <- NA
  data.table(matrix(v, ncol=ncol))
}
f_dowle3 = function(DT) {
  for (j in seq_len(ncol(DT)))
    set(DT,which(is.na(DT[[j]])),j,0)
}

set.seed(1)
dt1 = create_dt(2e5, 200, 0.1)
dim(dt1)
#[1] 200000    200
dt2 = copy(dt1)
system.time(f_dowle3(dt1))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.193   0.062   0.254 
system.time(setnafill(dt2, fill=0))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.633   0.000   0.020   ## setDTthreads(1) elapsed: 0.149
all.equal(dt1, dt2)
#[1] TRUE

set.seed(1)
dt1 = create_dt(2e7, 200, 0.1)
dim(dt1)
#[1] 20000000    200
dt2 = copy(dt1)
system.time(f_dowle3(dt1))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 22.997  18.179  41.496
system.time(setnafill(dt2, fill=0))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 39.604  36.805   3.798 
all.equal(dt1, dt2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: That's a great feature! Are you planning to add support for character columns? Then it could be used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59054095/how-to-replace-na-value-with-previous-non-na-value-given-to-same-id).

Comment: @ismirsehregal yes, you can track this feature here https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3992

Answer (score 19):

```
library(data.table)

DT = data.table(a=c(1,"A",NA),b=c(4,NA,"B"))

DT
    a  b
1:  1  4
2:  A NA
3: NA  B

DT[,lapply(.SD,function(x){ifelse(is.na(x),0,x)})]
   a b
1: 1 4
2: A 0
3: 0 B
```

Just for reference, slower compared to gdata or data.matrix, but uses only the data.table package and can deal with non numerical entries.

Comment: You could probably both avoid `ifelse` and update by reference by doing `DT[, names(DT) := lapply(.SD, function(x) {x[is.na(x)] <- "0" ; x})]`. And I doubt it will be slower that than answers you've mentioned.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a solution using `NAToUnknown` in the `gdata` package. I have used Andrie's solution to create a huge data table and also included time comparisons with Andrie's solution.

```
# CREATE DATA TABLE
dt1 = create_dt(2e5, 200, 0.1)

# FUNCTIONS TO SET NA TO ZERO   
f_gdata  = function(dt, un = 0) gdata::NAToUnknown(dt, un)
f_Andrie = function(dt) remove_na(dt)

# COMPARE SOLUTIONS AND TIMES
system.time(a_gdata  <- f_gdata(dt1))

user  system elapsed 
4.224   2.962   7.388 

system.time(a_andrie <- f_Andrie(dt1))

 user  system elapsed 
4.635   4.730  20.060 

identical(a_gdata, g_andrie)  

TRUE
```

Comment: +1 Good find.  Interesting - it's the first time I see timings with similar `user` time but really big difference in `elapsed` time.

Comment: @Andrie I tried using `rbenchmark` to benchmark solutions using more replications, but got an out of memory error possibly due to the size of the data frame. if you can run `benchmark` on both these solutions with multiple replications, those results would be interesting as i am not really sure why i am getting a 3x speedup

Comment: @Ramnath To get things correct, the timings in this answer are for `ncol=5` I think (should take much longer) due to the bug in `create_dt`.

Answer (score 6):

My understanding is that the secret to fast operations in R is to utilise vector (or arrays, which are vectors under the hood.)

In this solution I make use of a `data.matrix` which is an `array` but behave a bit like a `data.frame`.  Because it is an array, you can use a very simple vector substitution to replace the `NA`s:

A little helper function to remove the `NA`s.  The essence is a single line of code.  I only do this to measure execution time.

```
remove_na <- function(x){
  dm <- data.matrix(x)
  dm[is.na(dm)] <- 0
  data.table(dm)
}
```

A little helper function to create a `data.table` of a given size.

```
create_dt <- function(nrow=5, ncol=5, propNA = 0.5){
  v <- runif(nrow * ncol)
  v[sample(seq_len(nrow*ncol), propNA * nrow*ncol)] <- NA
  data.table(matrix(v, ncol=ncol))
}
```

Demonstration on a tiny sample:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
dt <- create_dt(5, 5, 0.5)

dt
            V1        V2        V3        V4        V5
[1,]        NA 0.8983897        NA 0.4976992 0.9347052
[2,] 0.3721239 0.9446753        NA 0.7176185 0.2121425
[3,] 0.5728534        NA 0.6870228 0.9919061        NA
[4,]        NA        NA        NA        NA 0.1255551
[5,] 0.2016819        NA 0.7698414        NA        NA

remove_na(dt)
            V1        V2        V3        V4        V5
[1,] 0.0000000 0.8983897 0.0000000 0.4976992 0.9347052
[2,] 0.3721239 0.9446753 0.0000000 0.7176185 0.2121425
[3,] 0.5728534 0.0000000 0.6870228 0.9919061 0.0000000
[4,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1255551
[5,] 0.2016819 0.0000000 0.7698414 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

Comment: That's a very nice example dataset. I'll try and improve on `remove_na`. That timing of 21.57s includes the `create_dt` (including `runif` and `sample`) together with the `remove_na`. Any chance you could edit to split out the 2 times?

Comment: Is there a small bug in `create_dt`? It seems to always create a 5 column data.table regardless of `ncol` passed in.

Comment: @MatthewDowle Well spotted.  Error removed (as well as the timings)

Comment: Converting to matrix will only work properly if all columns are the same type.

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of completeness, another way to replace NAs with 0 is to use

```
f_rep <- function(dt) {
dt[is.na(dt)] <- 0
return(dt)
}
```

To compare results and times I have incorporated all approaches mentioned so far.

```
set.seed(1)
dt1 <- create_dt(2e5, 200, 0.1)
dt2 <- dt1
dt3 <- dt1

system.time(res1 <- f_gdata(dt1))
   User      System verstrichen 
   3.62        0.22        3.84 
system.time(res2 <- f_andrie(dt1))
   User      System verstrichen 
   2.95        0.33        3.28 
system.time(f_dowle2(dt2))
   User      System verstrichen 
   0.78        0.00        0.78 
system.time(f_dowle3(dt3))
   User      System verstrichen 
   0.17        0.00        0.17 
system.time(res3 <- f_unknown(dt1))
   User      System verstrichen 
   6.71        0.84        7.55 
system.time(res4 <- f_rep(dt1))
   User      System verstrichen 
   0.32        0.00        0.32 

identical(res1, res2) & identical(res2, res3) & identical(res3, res4) & identical(res4, dt2) & identical(dt2, dt3)
[1] TRUE
```

So the new approach is slightly slower than `f_dowle3` but faster than all the other approaches. But to be honest, this is against my Intuition of the data.table Syntax and I have no idea why this works. Can anybody enlighten me?

Comment: Yes I checked them, this is why I have included the pairwise identicals.

Comment: Here's a reason why it's not the idiomatic way - http://stackoverflow.com/a/20545629/

Answer (score 4):

Using the `fifelse` function from the newest `data.table` versions 1.12.6, it is even 10 times faster than `NAToUnknown` in the `gdata` package:

```
z = data.table(x = sample(c(NA_integer_, 1), 2e7, TRUE))
system.time(z[,x1 := gdata::NAToUnknown(x, 0)])

#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.798   0.323   1.173
```

```
system.time(z[,x2:= fifelse(is.na(x), 0, x)])

#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.172   0.093   0.113
```

Comment: Can you add some timing comparisons to this answer?  I think `f_dowle3` will still be faster: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7249454/345660

Answer (score 3):

To generalize to many columns you could use this approach (using previous sample data but adding a column):

```
z = data.table(x = sample(c(NA_integer_, 1), 2e7, TRUE), y = sample(c(NA_integer_, 1), 2e7, TRUE))

z[, names(z) := lapply(.SD, function(x) fifelse(is.na(x), 0, x))]
```

Didn't test for the speed though

Answer (score 1):

```
> DT = data.table(a=LETTERS[c(1,1:3,4:7)],b=sample(c(15,51,NA,12,21),8,T),key="a")
> DT
   a  b
1: A 12
2: A NA
3: B 15
4: C NA
5: D 51
6: E NA
7: F 15
8: G 51
> DT[is.na(b),b:=0]
> DT
   a  b
1: A 12
2: A  0
3: B 15
4: C  0
5: D 51
6: E  0
7: F 15
8: G 51
>
```

Comment: And how would you generalize this to more than one columns though?

Comment: @DavidArenburg just write a for loop. This should be the accepted answer: it's the simplest!

Answer (score 1):

A fast alternative is `collapse::replace_NA`, which by default replaces NAs with 0.

```r
library(collapse)
replace_NA(df)
```

Microbenchmark on a data.frame with 10 columns of 1M rows and 10% NAs.

```r
# Unit: milliseconds
#        expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#    f_dowle3 30.9308 34.44890 50.46713 47.33065 58.04780 160.4836   100
#   setnafill 10.3389 10.92065 12.34867 11.79305 13.41090  22.0207   100
#  replace_NA  9.9896 10.98030 15.19177 12.87030 17.00505  83.5094   100
```

---

Code:

```r
library(data.table)
library(collapse)
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(1)
df <- as.data.frame(replicate(10, runif(1e6)))
df <- na_insert(df, prop = 0.1)
dt <- df
setDT(dt)

f_dowle3 = function() {
  for (j in seq_len(ncol(dt)))
    set(dt, which(is.na(dt[[j]])),j,0)
}

mb <- 
  microbenchmark(
  f_dowle3 = f_dowle3(),
  setnafill = data.table::setnafill(dt, fill = 0),
  replace_NA = collapse::replace_NA(dt, set = TRUE)
)
```