# Replace all 0 values to NA

Tags: r, r-faq

I have a dataframe with some numeric columns. Some row has a 0 value which should be considered as null in statistical analysis. What is the fastest way to replace all the 0 value to NULL in R?

Comment: I don't think you want/can replace with NULL values, but NA serves that purpose in R lingo.

Answer (score 346, accepted):

Replacing all zeroes to NA:

```
df[df == 0] <- NA
```

**Explanation**

**1.** It is not `NULL` what you should want to replace zeroes with. As it says in `?'NULL'`,

> NULL represents the null object in R

which is unique and, I guess, can be seen as the most uninformative and empty object.<sup>1</sup> Then it becomes not so surprising that

```
data.frame(x = c(1, NULL, 2))
#   x
# 1 1
# 2 2
```

That is, R does not reserve any space for this null object.<sup>2</sup> Meanwhile, looking at `?'NA'` we see that

> NA is a logical constant of length 1 which contains a missing value
>   indicator. NA can be coerced to any other vector type except raw.

Importantly, `NA` is of length 1 so that R reserves some space for it. E.g.,

```
data.frame(x = c(1, NA, 2))
#    x
# 1  1
# 2 NA
# 3  2
```

Also, the data frame structure requires all the columns to have the same number of elements so that there can be no "holes" (i.e., `NULL` values).

Now you could replace zeroes by `NULL` in a data frame in the sense of completely removing all the rows containing at least one zero. When using, e.g., `var`, `cov`, or `cor`, that is actually equivalent to first replacing zeroes with `NA` and setting the value of `use` as `"complete.obs"`. Typically, however, this is unsatisfactory as it leads to extra information loss.

**2.** Instead of running some sort of loop, in the solution I use `df == 0` vectorization. `df == 0` returns (try it) a matrix of the same size as `df`, with the entries `TRUE` and `FALSE`. Further, we are also allowed to pass this matrix to the subsetting `[...]` (see `?'['`). Lastly, while the result of `df[df == 0]` is perfectly intuitive, it may seem strange that `df[df == 0] <- NA` gives the desired effect. The assignment operator `<-` is indeed not always so smart and does not work in this way with some other objects, but it does so with data frames; see `?'<-'`.

<sub><sup>1</sup> The empty set in the set theory feels somehow related.</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup> Another similarity with the set theory: the empty set is a subset of every set, but we do not reserve any space for it.</sub>

Comment: What would the equivalent syntax be for a data.table object?

Comment: I see you've gotten a lot of votes but do not think this appropriately covers the edge cases of non-numeric columns with values of "0" which were not requested to be set to <NA>.

Comment: Note to self: If it does not work and the dataframe was parsed from csv, make sure your values don't contain whitespaces at the start/end like " ?".

Answer (score 52):

Let me assume that your data.frame is a mix of different datatypes and not all columns need to be modified.

to modify only columns 12 to 18 (of the total 21), just do this

```
df[, 12:18][df[, 12:18] == 0] <- NA
```

Comment: This works for me, while the accepted answer does not

Comment: This works, and is more flexible than the accepted answer.

Comment: The double subset with`[]` is great! So obvious and still so concealed :)

Comment: @userJT - what if I want to select the columns with their name than position? e.g. 300 columns with name : age1,age2,age3,age4 ...... age300

Answer (score 42):

`dplyr::na_if()` is an option:

```
library(dplyr)  

df <- data_frame(col1 = c(1, 2, 3, 0),
                 col2 = c(0, 2, 3, 4),
                 col3 = c(1, 0, 3, 0),
                 col4 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))

na_if(df, 0)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
   col1  col2  col3 col4 
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1    NA     1 a    
2     2     2    NA b    
3     3     3     3 c    
4    NA     4    NA d
```

Comment: `na_if` doesn't take data.frame or tibble in my version

Answer (score 23):

An alternative way without the `[<-` function:

A sample data frame `dat` (shamelessly copied from @Chase's answer):

```
dat

  x y
1 0 2
2 1 2
3 1 1
4 2 1
5 0 0
```

Zeroes can be replaced with `NA` by the `is.na<-` function:

```
is.na(dat) <- !dat


dat

   x  y
1 NA  2
2  1  2
3  1  1
4  2  1
5 NA NA
```

Answer (score 14):

```
#Sample data
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(x = sample(0:2, 5, TRUE), y = sample(0:2, 5, TRUE))
#-----
  x y
1 0 2
2 1 2
3 1 1
4 2 1
5 0 0

#replace zeros with NA
dat[dat==0] <- NA
#-----
   x  y
1 NA  2
2  1  2
3  1  1
4  2  1
5 NA NA
```

Answer (score 14):

Because someone asked for the Data.Table version of this, and because the given data.frame solution does not work with data.table, I am providing the solution below.

Basically, use the `:=` operator --> `DT[x == 0, x := NA]`

```
library("data.table")

status = as.data.table(occupationalStatus)

head(status, 10)
    origin destination  N
 1:      1           1 50
 2:      2           1 16
 3:      3           1 12
 4:      4           1 11
 5:      5           1  2
 6:      6           1 12
 7:      7           1  0
 8:      8           1  0
 9:      1           2 19
10:      2           2 40


status[N == 0, N := NA]

head(status, 10)
    origin destination  N
 1:      1           1 50
 2:      2           1 16
 3:      3           1 12
 4:      4           1 11
 5:      5           1  2
 6:      6           1 12
 7:      7           1 NA
 8:      8           1 NA
 9:      1           2 19
10:      2           2 40
```

Comment: Or `for (j in names(DT)); set(DT,which(DT[[j]] == 0),j,NA)`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7249454/4241780) for a more detailed discussion of using data.table to find and replace values.

Answer (score 9):

In case anyone arrives here via google looking for the *opposite* (i.e. how to replace all NAs in a data.frame with 0), the answer is

```
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
```

OR

Using dplyr / tidyverse

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% replace(is.na(.), 0)
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is my contribution for those who are struggling with datasets with different types of columns with multiple values representing missing data.

```
dat <- data_frame(numA = c(1, 0, 3, 4),
             numB = c(NA, 2, 3, 4),
             strC = c("0", "1.2", "NA", "2.4"),
             strD = c("Yes", "Yes", "missing", "No"))
```

Let's say in this data we want to replace 0 in numeric columns with `NA` as well as 'NA' and 'missing' values in character/string values with `NA`. Notice that 'NA' in `strC` column is a character type value, not the desired `NA`.

```
dat
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  numA   numB  strC  strD   
  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr> <chr>  
1     1     NA 0     Yes    
2     0      2 1.2   Yes    
3     3      3 'NA'  missing
4     4      4 2.4   No
```

First, an obvious case, notice that when converting a character column to numeric values any non-numeric string value is coerced to `NA`.

```
as.numeric(dat$strC)
[1] 0.0 1.2  NA 2.4
```

### Answer with indexing:

```
dat[dat == "NA" | dat =="missing"] <- NA
```

However, do NOT use that for 0 because it changes both numeric and character 0s to `NA`. This is because `"0" == 0` returns `TRUE` in R.

### dplyr::na_if method:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  lapply(na_if, y = "missing") %>%
  lapply(na_if, y = "NA") %>%
  lapply(na_if, y = 0) %>%  # DONT DO THIS! It converts string 0s to NA as well!
  data.frame()
```

Here we apply `na_if` function to each column of the data. Since `na_if` does not accept multiple values to be converted to `NA` we need to write multiple lines of code for each value to be converted into `NA`. However, simple usage of this function with `0` converts both the numeric and character `0`s into `NA`. We need to do something else!

### Using mutate across method with na_if function:

This is my favorite solution. Here we check the column type and apply `na_if` function as necessary. The character `0` is untouched, whereas all desired values are converted into `NA`.

```
dat %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~na_if(., 0))) %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.character), ~na_if(., "NA"))) %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.character), ~na_if(., "missing")))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
   numA  numB strC  strD 
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1    NA 0     Yes  
2    NA     2 1.2   Yes  
3     3     3 NA    NA   
4     4     4 2.4   No
```

### Finally, `nariar` package can be used

`nariar` is a recent package that introduces a variety of `replace_with_` functions.

```
library(naniar)
```

Replace all 'NA' and 'missing' values to `NA`:

```
dat %>%
  replace_with_na_all(~.x %in% c("NA", "missing"))
```

but if you use this with `0`s, it still erroneously converts the character 0 to `NA`:

```
dat %>%
  replace_with_na_all(~.x %in% c(0, "NA", "missing"))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
   numA  numB strC  strD 
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1    NA NA    Yes  
2    NA     2 1.2   Yes  
3     3     3 NA    NA   
4     4     4 2.4   No
#strC's first element should not be NA here!
```

So, we have to specify column type using replace_with_na_if:

```
dat %>%
  replace_with_na_if(is.character, ~.x %in% c("NA", "missing")) %>%
  replace_with_na_if(is.numeric, ~.x %in% c(0))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
   numA  numB strC  strD 
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     1    NA 0     Yes  
2    NA     2 1.2   Yes  
3     3     3 NA    NA   
4     4     4 2.4   No
```

We achieved the desired outcome. I hope all this is helpful :)

Answer (score 4):

You can replace `0` with `NA` only in numeric fields (i.e. excluding things like factors), but it works on a column-by-column basis:

```
col[col == 0 & is.numeric(col)] <- NA
```

With a function, you can apply this to your whole data frame:

```
changetoNA <- function(colnum,df) {
    col <- df[,colnum]
    if (is.numeric(col)) {  #edit: verifying column is numeric
        col[col == -1 & is.numeric(col)] <- NA
    }
    return(col)
}
df <- data.frame(sapply(1:5, changetoNA, df))
```

Although you could replace the `1:5` with the number of columns in your data frame, or with `1:ncol(df)`.

Comment: I am not sure this is correct solution. What about columns 6 and more. They will get cut.

Comment: That's why I suggested replacing `1:5` with `1:ncol(df)` at the end. I didn't want to make the equation overly complex or difficult to read.

Comment: but  what if in the columns 6 and 7 - the datatype is char and no replacement should be done. In my problem, I need replacement only in columns 12 to 15 but the whole df has 21 columns (many must not be touched at all).

Comment: For your data frame you could just change the `1:5` to the column numbers you want changed, like `12:15`, but if you wanted to confirm that it will only affect numeric columns then just wrap the second line of the function in an if statement, like this: `if (is.numeric(col)) { col[col == -1 & is.numeric(col)] <- NA }`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to `replace` all 0 with `NA` using `mutate_all` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,0,4,2),
                 v2 = c(3,1,0,0))
df
#>   v1 v2
#> 1  1  3
#> 2  0  1
#> 3  4  0
#> 4  2  0
mutate_all(df, ~replace(., .==0, NA))
#>   v1 v2
#> 1  1  3
#> 2 NA  1
#> 3  4 NA
#> 4  2 NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Also `~na.if(.,0)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are like me and landed here while wondering how to replace ALL values in a dataframe with NA, it's just:

```html
df[,] <- NA
```