# How to use linear regression in R if some values of one of predictors are missing?

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, linear-regression

`y` is expected to be a linear function of predictors `x1`, `x2`, ..., `xn`
so I use `glm` to find a regression
but some values of one of parameters (`x1`, for example) are missing (`NA` in input data)
they are defined, they are just unknown
What would be the correct way to use `x1` in regression?

Comment: I believe that the [default glm behavior is to omit NAs](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/glm.html).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the context of the problem. 
Some solutions are:

- omit NA or exclude the instance
- substitute per a default value (0, average of the others)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace missing values with Zero using following code

```
myData[myData == ''] <- 0
```

Also you can replace them using Row mean or Column mean using following code

```
for(i in 1:nrow(myData)){
myData[i,is.na(myData[,i])] <- mean(myData[i,], na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

or

```
for(i in 1:ncol(myData)){
myData[is.na(myData[,i]), i] <- mean(myData[,i], na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

If you already have 0 as missing value and you want to replace it with NA, use following code:

```
myData[myData == 0] <- NA
```

as discussed here [Replace all 0 values to NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036989/replace-all-0-values-to-na)