# convert all zeros of a matrix in R to NA

Tags: r, matrix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace all 0 values to NA in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036989/replace-all-0-values-to-na-in-r)

Going off of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161836/how-do-i-replace-na-values-with-zeros-in-r). Is there a similar function in R such as `x[is.na(x)] <- 0` except that it will changes every zero in a matrix to NA?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
x[x == 0] <- NA
```

For example:

```
x = matrix(rep(0:1, 50), nrow=10)
x[x == 0] <- NA
print(x)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
# [2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
# [3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
# [4,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
# [5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
# [6,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
# [7,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
# [8,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
# [9,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
#[10,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
```

Comment: What would the equivalent syntax be for a data.table object?

Comment: @dadrivr There's no particularly easy equivalent for a data.table. If the data.table is entirely numeric I'd recommend turning it into a matrix, doing this, and turning it back. If it includes factors you could try adapting [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235657/fastest-way-to-replace-nas-in-a-large-data-table), only in reverse