# How to change all 0's in a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, sapply

I would like to change all 0's to, say 0.0001, in a list of dataframes to avoid -Inf when take log. So followed the instruction from [Replace all 0 values to NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036989/replace-all-0-values-to-na), I wrote my function as

```
set_zero_as_value <- function(x, value=0.0001){
    x[x == 0] <- value
}
```

However when I use `sapply` to my data `sapply(a,set_zero_as_value)`, the result returned as

```
   s1    s2 
1e-04 1e-04
```

And further check the list a, the 0 in `a` does not change at all. Is there a solution for this?

PS: list `a` can be created as

```
> a = NULL
> a$s1 = rbind(cbind(0,1,2),cbind(3,4,5))
> a$s2 = rbind(cbind(0,1,2),cbind(3,4,5))
```

Comment: Your function needs to return `x`.

Comment: And (hopefully I don't need to point this out) you need to assign the result to something, e.g. `a <- sapply(a,set_zero_as_value)`

Comment: So I must to assign the results? Can I simply modify a, since if the dataframe is very large, there would be redundancy. Or I just rm it later.

Comment: @lolibility use a `data.table` from the `data.table` package to *pass-by-reference*. R is obstensibly *pass-by-value* and will perform copy-on-modify of almost all objects you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pmax` inside of `lapply` call, no need to define `set_zero_as_value` since `pmax` does what you need. Let's suppose your list is:

```
list.DF <-list(structure(list(a = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
0L), b = c(1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L), c = c(5L, 
1L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 2L)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(
    d = c(2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 2L), e = c(4L, 
    3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 4L), f = c(2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L)), .Names = c("d", "e", "f"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Now applying your desired transformation:

```
> lapply(list.DF, function(x) sapply(x, pmax, 0.0001))
```

---

If you want to use your `set_zero_as_value` function, then add `return(x)` at the end of it.

```
set_zero_as_value <- function(x, value=0.0001){
  x[x == 0] <- value
  return(x)
}

lapply(list.DF, function(x) sapply(x, set_zero_as_value))
```

This will produce the same result as before.

Comment: +1 but... your `pmax` solution will also change values in the data that are `x > 0 & x < 0.0001` which *may* be undesirable.