# Function to change blanks to NA

Tags: r, function, na, missing-data

I'm trying to write a function that turns empty strings into NA. A summary of one of my column looks like this:

```
      a   b 
 12 210 468
```

I'd like to change the 12 empty values to NA. I also have a few other factor columns for which I'd like to change empty values to NA, so I borrowed some stuff from here and there to come up with this:

```
# change nulls to NAs
nullToNA <- function(df){

  # split df into numeric & non-numeric functions
  a<-df[,sapply(df, is.numeric), drop = FALSE]
  b<-df[,sapply(df, Negate(is.numeric)), drop = FALSE]

  # Change empty strings to NA
  b<-b[lapply(b,function(x) levels(x) <- c(levels(x), NA) ),] # add NA level
  b<-b[lapply(b,function(x) x[x=="",]<- NA),]                 # change Null to NA

  # Put the columns back together
  d<-cbind(a,b)
  d[, names(df)]
}
```

However, I'm getting this error:

> ```
> > foo<-nullToNA(bar)  
> Error in x[x == "", ] <- NA : incorrect number of subscripts on matrix  
> Called from: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
> ```

I have tried the answer found here: [Replace all 0 values to NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036989/replace-all-0-values-to-na) but it changes all my columns to numeric values.

Comment: why not the `is.null()` function instead of `x==""`? Maybe there is nothing to be found. Have you checked whether your `levels` returns anything. you can check the inside of your function step by step with your data. ignore the function and go line by line with your data the inside of your function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace all 0 values to NA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036989/replace-all-0-values-to-na)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can directly index fields that match a logical criterion. So you can just write:

```
df[is_empty(df)] = NA
```

Where `is_empty` is your comparison, e.g. `df == ""`:

```
df[df == ""] = NA
```

But note that `is.null(df)` won’t work, and would be weird anyway<sup>1</sup>. I would advise against merging the logic for columns of different types, though! Instead, handle them separately.

---

<sup>1</sup> You’ll almost never encounter `NULL` inside a table since that only works if the underlying vector is a `list`. You can create matrices and data.frames with this constraint, but then `is.null(df)` will never be `TRUE` because the `NULL` values are wrapped inside the list).

Comment: `is_empty` is not a function, but I used `b[b==""] = NA` and that worked.

Comment: @TravisHeeter I used `is_empty` as an arbitrary placeholder.

Comment: Adapted above solution to:  df[df == "NULL"] <- NA for my problem and it still works! +1 Thank you @KonradRudolph

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
    df[df == 'NULL'] <- NA
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just:

```
df[apply(df, 2, function(x) x=="")] = NA
```

Works fine for me, at least on simple examples.

Comment: (1) `""` ≠ `NULL`! (2) `apply` isn’t needed.

Comment: Agree with (2), I overcomplicated it :)  But can you even have NULL values in R vectors?.. Anyway, OP's example function is looking for empty strings, so I figured that's what he wanted to replace.

Comment: Admittedly having `NULL` values in tables is rare. It only works if the underlying (column) vector is a `list`.

Comment: Not so weird, at least not anymore. The tidyverse function `pivot_wider` puts NULL in for missing values.

Answer (score 0):

This is the function I used to solve this issue.

```
null_na=function(vector){
  new_vector=rep(NA,length(vector))
  for(i in 1:length(vector))
    if(vector[i]== ""){new_vector[i]=NA}else if(is.na(vector[i])) 
      {new_vector[i]=NA}else{new_vector[i]=vector[i]}
  return(new_vector)
}
```

Just plug in the column or vector you are having an issue with.