# Detecting NA's in a DataFrame

Tags: r, dataframe, na

After I read a csv in RStudio, some columns were able to detect Null Values (NA) but others not. `View(df)`displays some columns with blank spaces & not as NA. How do I go about this so that null values can be represented as NA?

```
# Create example data frame
dat <- data.frame(
  Date = c("04/12/2011", "03/01/2002", "02/07/2002", "01/02/2001", "", ""),
  A = "",
  B = c(NA, 1981, NA, 1981, 1950, 1989)
)
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not post screenshot. Next time when you ask a question, please create a reproducible example of your dataset, such as what I did in my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While reading the csv itself you can specify to replace your blank cells by NA

```
df <-read.csv("data.csv", header=T, na.strings=c("","NA"))
```

If there are spaces in the blank cells, you can specify :

```
na.strings=c(""," ","NA")
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean that some rows do not show any date?

You could try using

```
df[df == ""] = NA
```

as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40379021/function-to-change-null-to-na)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply` and `replace` to replace "" with `NA`.

```
# Create example data frame
dat <- data.frame(
  Date = c("04/12/2011", "03/01/2002", "02/07/2002", "01/02/2001", "", ""),
  A = "",
  B = c(NA, 1981, NA, 1981, 1950, 1989)
)

dat
#         Date A    B
# 1 04/12/2011     NA
# 2 03/01/2002   1981
# 3 02/07/2002     NA
# 4 01/02/2001   1981
# 5              1950
# 6              1989

# Replace the "" with NA
dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(x){
  replace(x, x %in% "", NA)
})

dat
#         Date    A    B
# 1 04/12/2011 <NA>   NA
# 2 03/01/2002 <NA> 1981
# 3 02/07/2002 <NA>   NA
# 4 01/02/2001 <NA> 1981
# 5       <NA> <NA> 1950
# 6       <NA> <NA> 1989
```

Comment: As others have said you can set the missing values when you read in the csv file, if you already have your dataframe then you can use the handy `na_if` command from `dplyr` package

`library(dplyr)`
`?na_if`

For your dataframe, something like;
`dat$Date <- na_if(dat$Date, '')'

Comment: @sorearm Thanks for the tips.