# How to change the value in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to find a quick way to replace the values (strings) in several columns of a dataframe.

```
id = c(2, 3, 5) 
v1 = c("aa", "bb", "cc") 
v2 = c("ee", "aa", "cc") 
df = data.frame(id,v1,v2) 

print(df)

  id v1 v2
1  2 aa ee
2  3 bb aa
3  5 cc cc
```

What I want is to replace all instances of "aa" by "uu" and of "cc" by "rr"

```
  id v1 v2
1  2 uu ee
2  3 bb uu
3  5 rr rr
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option using `lapply`:

```
fun <- function(x) {
    x[x == "aa"] <- "uu"
    x[x == "cc"] <- "rr"
    return(x)
}
df <- data.frame(lapply(df, fun))
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_replace_all` from the `{stringr}` package

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  map_df(~str_replace_all(., c("aa" = "uu", "cc" = "rr")))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(plyr)
df[c("v1", "v2")] <-lapply(df[c("v1", "v2")], function(x) mapvalues( x, c("aa", "cc"), c("uu", "rr")))
```

Comment: You could use `mapvalues()` in `mutate_at()`: `mutate_at(df, vars(v1:v2), funs(mapvalues(., c("aa", "cc"), c("uu", "rr"))))`

Comment: Note that dplyr has replaced the plyr library!

Comment: Thanks for info and useful alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you:

```
library(car)
df[,2:3] <- lapply(df[,2:3], function(x) recode(x, "'aa' = 'uu'; 'cc' = 'rr'"))
```

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly. But what if I want to replace multiple values by one? `df[,2:3] <- lapply(df[,2:3], function(x) recode(x, "'aa' = 'uu'; 'cc' = 'rr';'ee'='rr'"))`. Is there a simple and more efficient way to it?

Comment: You can do it like this: `"c('cc', 'ee') = 'rr'"`

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>% mutate_if(is.character, funs(case_when(  . == 'aa' ~ 'uu'
                                              , . == 'cc' ~ 'rr'
                                              , T ~ .)))
```

If the columns are factors you can do

```
df %>% mutate_if(is.factor, funs(case_when(   . == 'aa' ~ 'uu'
                                            , . == 'cc' ~ 'rr'
                                            , T ~ as.character(.))))
```

Answer (score 0):

First we structure our lookup of replacement values :

```
lkp = list(aa = 'uu', cc = 'rr')
```

Then we can use it directly in `dplyr::recode`, through `do.call`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  mutate_at(vars(v1,v2),funs(do.call(recode,c(.x=list(.),lkp))))
#   id v1 v2
# 1  2 uu ee
# 2  3 bb uu
# 3  5 rr rr
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer from [Replace all 0 values to NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036989/replace-all-0-values-to-na)
, you can subset `df` using [`[]`](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html#data-types) to find the values of interest and replace them with their preferred values.

```
# create data
id <- c(2, 3, 5) 
v1 <- c("aa", "bb", "cc") 
v2 <- c("ee", "aa", "cc") 
df <- data.frame( id, v1, v2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE )

# view the data
df
#   id v1 v2
# 1  2 aa ee
# 2  3 bb aa
# 3  5 cc cc

# find all instances of "aa"
# and replace with "uu"
df[ df == "aa" ] <- "uu"

# find all instances of "cc"
# and replace with "rr"
df[ df == "cc" ] <- "rr"

# view the data
df
#   id v1 v2
# 1  2 uu ee
# 2  3 bb uu
# 3  5 rr rr

# end of script #
```