# Removing a custom (second) class from a dataset/variable

Tags: r, class, plm, hmisc

I have been using a class from the `hmisc` package called `haven_labelled` (or sometimes just `labelled`). It purpose is to import the column labels from a Stata `.dta` dataset. When trying to use `plm` on a dataframe I got the error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘c("pseries", "haven_labelled")’ to a data.frame
```

Classes are as follows:

```
> class(actualdataset)
[1] "pdata.frame" "data.frame"
> class(actualdataset$examplevar)
[1] "pseries"        "haven_labelled"
```

As a results I would like remove the `haven_labelled` class from this database. I have regretfully been unable to recreate the error. I think it has to do with the `var` from my `actualdataset` being of a double class which includes have `haven_labelled`. Please see the following example dataset.

```
library(data.table)
library(plm)
library(Hmisc)
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(panelID = sample(50,50),                                                    # Creates a panel ID
                      Country = c(rep("A",30),rep("B",50), rep("C",20)),       
                      some_NA = sample(0:5, 6),                                             
                      some_NA_factor = sample(0:5, 6),         
                      Group = c(rep(1,20),rep(2,20),rep(3,20),rep(4,20),rep(5,20)),
                      Time = rep(seq(as.Date("2010-01-03"), length=20, by="1 month") - 1,5),
                      norm = round(runif(100)/10,2),
                      Income = sample(100,100),
                      Happiness = sample(10,10),
                      Sex = round(rnorm(10,0.75,0.3),2),
                      Age = round(rnorm(10,0.75,0.3),2),
                      Educ = round(rnorm(10,0.75,0.3),2))           
DT [, uniqueID := .I]                                                                        # Creates a unique ID     
DT[DT == 0] <- NA                                                                            # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036989/replace-all-0-values-to-na
DT$some_NA_factor <- factor(DT$some_NA_factor)
labels <- data.table::fread("Varcode Variables
                         panelID a
                         Country b
                         Group c
                         Time d
                         norm e
                         Income f
                         Happiness g
                         Sex h
                         Age i
                         Educ j
                         uniqueID k                         
                         ", header = TRUE)
for (i in seq_len(ncol(DT))) { 
    label(DT[[i]]) <-  labels$Variables[match(names(DT)[i], labels$Varcode)] 
 }
DTp <- plm::pdata.frame(DT, index= c("panelID", "Time"))
result <- plm(Happiness ~ Income, data=DTp, model="within")

> class(DTp)
[1] "pdata.frame" "data.frame"
> class(DTp$Income)
[1] "pseries"  "labelled" "integer"
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I was thinking about something as follows:

```
for for (i in seq_len(ncol(DT)) {
    if (sapply(DT, function(x) class(x)[1L]) == "haven_labelled") { 
        attr(DT[,i],"class[1L]") <- "integer"
    }
 }
```

EDIT 2: The answer prevented any errors when applying `plm`. Regretfully somehow all `coefficients`, `standard errors` are zero. `P-values` and `t-values` are `NA`. I am not sure what causes this.

Comment: What happens if you run: `class(DTp$Income) <- "pseries" ` ?

Comment: Check `attributes(DTp$Income)`, `attributes(DTp$Income)$class` and `attr(DTp$Income,"class")`, in this case `attr(DTp$Income,"class") <- c("pseries","integer")` may help.

Comment: @A.Suliman Thank you for your comment. I was looking for a bit more general solution that I could used on the entire (actual) dataset. I edited the original post to explain better what I was hoping for. Would you mind taking a look?

Comment: @Ben Nutzer Thank you for your comment. I tried your approach with the whole dataset, but turned it into a pseries list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution based on the provided dataset *DTp*, change `labelled` and `labelled_ch` according to your original dataset

```
for (i in seq_len(ncol(DTp))) {
  if (any(class(DTp[,i]) == "labelled")) {
    #browser()
    ind = which(class(DTp[,i])=="labelled")
    attr(DTp[,i],"class")[ind] <- "labelled_ch"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I got passed the `plm` stage without error now.

Comment: See the second edit. I am not sure it is related to the original questions that is why I removed it. The `lm` still works..

Comment: Ah, good to know! With the example dataset I am however not really sure that it is that surprising, as I did not put any thought into the data. I have however now been able to get a result with `plm` and the actual dataset. I think I have to be more careful with what I put into the regression. Thanks a lot for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question while looking for a solution to get rid of a secondary class (`avector` in my case). I always got errors like this in currenct R versions:

```
Can't convert `y` <double> to match type of `x` <avector>.
```

Thanks for the idea of using the `class()` function. Here is what I made of it:

```
simplify_classes = function(x, strip=c("avector")) {
    # We may handle single variables ...
    if ((length(class(x)) > 1) || (class(x) != "data.frame")) {
        class(x) = setdiff(class(x), strip)
        return(x)
    }
    # ... or a data.frames of multiple variables
    dfn = data.frame(row.names = row.names(x))
    for (v in names(x)) {
        tmp = x[[v]]
        class(tmp) = setdiff(class(tmp), strip)
        dfn[[v]] = tmp
    }
    return(dfn)
}
```

This can be used with tidyverse for data frames

```
my_data %>% select(!!items) %>% simplify_classes() %>% str()
```

and for single variables as well

```
my_data$var_reverse = 6 - media$var %>% simplify_classes() %>% na_if(-9)
```

Hope, this saves you some time.