# A data.table solution to remove variables with more than a certain percentage NA

Tags: r, data.table, na

I have been using the following code to remove variables with too many `NA`'s:

```
DT <- DT[,colMeans(is.na(DT)) <= 0.1]
```

However, on a `data.table` this gives:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(panelID = sample(50,50),                                                    # Creates a panel ID
                      Country = c(rep("Albania",30),rep("Belarus",50), rep("Chilipepper",20)),       
                      some_NA = sample(0:5, 6),                                             
                      some_NA_factor = sample(0:5, 6),         
                      Group = c(rep(1,20),rep(2,20),rep(3,20),rep(4,20),rep(5,20)),
                      Time = rep(seq(as.Date("2010-01-03"), length=20, by="1 month") - 1,5),
                      norm = round(runif(100)/10,2),
                      Income = round(rnorm(10,-5,5),2),
                      Happiness = sample(10,10),
                      Sex = round(rnorm(10,0.75,0.3),2),
                      Age = sample(100,100),
                      Educ = round(rnorm(10,0.75,0.3),2))           
DT [, uniqueID := .I]                                                                        # Creates a unique ID     
DT[DT == 0] <- NA                                                                            # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036989/replace-all-0-values-to-na
DT$some_NA_factor <- factor(DT$some_NA_factor)

> DT <- DT[,colMeans(is.na(DT)) <= 0.1]
> DT
       panelID        Country        some_NA some_NA_factor          Group           Time           norm         Income      Happiness            Sex            Age 
          TRUE           TRUE          FALSE          FALSE           TRUE           TRUE           TRUE           TRUE           TRUE           TRUE           TRUE 
          Educ       uniqueID 
          TRUE           TRUE
```

Now I can obviously change my dataset to a dataframe each time and back, but I since I use large datasets, a data.table solution would be much more efficient. What is the correct `data.table` way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we need to subset the columns

```
DT[, DT[,colMeans(is.na(.SD)) <= 0.1], with = FALSE]
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively use `.SDcols`:

```
DT[, .SD, .SDcols = DT[, colMeans(is.na(.SD)) <= 0.1]]
```