# Converting the values in all columns to a certain value in tibble/dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I have a `tibble` object and I want to replace all of the columns except certain ones with a value (say `NA` or `0`). I can able to do it without pipes `%>%` but how can I do it with `%>%`?

```
library(tibble)  
dtf <- tibble(id = c('12', '22', '33', '40'),
              x1 = c(0, 2, 3, 4),
              a2 = c(1, 0, 3, 0),
              c5 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))

# This raises an error:
dtf %>% select(-id) <- NA

Error in dtf %>% select(-id) <- NA : could not find function "%>%<-"

# This works:
dtf[, colnames(dtf) != 'id'] <- NA
dtf
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  id    x1    a2    c5   
  <chr> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1 12    NA    NA    NA   
2 22    NA    NA    NA   
3 33    NA    NA    NA   
4 40    NA    NA    NA
```

I believe I should use `mutate()` or `mutate_all()` but I couldn't figure out. One similar [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51178156/2275286) offered `na_if()` for `NA` values but I cannot make it work for this case.

Comment: It is already `NA` Not clear

Comment: If you're running this code straight through, you've already assigned those values to become NA by the time you get to the `select` call. Any reason why you have to use pipes and can't just use the base solution? Asking because I've seen a lot of SO posts that insist on not relying on base R but without any reasoning

Comment: Also `na_if` is for replacing a value with `NA` *if* it is some other value. In this case, you're just trying to make everything NA, not depend on any condition, right?

Comment: Edited the code in order to make it clear. It was confusing. Correct, I want to make everything NA, or some other value, without any condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the intention is to update the columns, use `mutate_at`

```
library(dplyr)
dtf <- dtf %>% 
           mutate_at(vars(-id), ~ NA)
```

If we need to replace with 0

```
dtf <- dtf %>%
          mutate_at(vars(-id), replace_na, 0)
```

Comment: The first one is the one I wanted. I want to set a single value to all columns, it can be all `NA`s or some other value. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you want to do.

1. Mutate all variables in the same way and select by name/place:

```
df %>%
mutate_at(.vars = c("x1","a2","c5"), funs(case_when(is.na(.) ~ 0,TRUE ~ .)))

# or 

df %>%
mutate_at(.vars = -id, funs(case_when(is.na(.) ~ 0,TRUE ~ .)))
```

2. Mutate all variables in the same way and select by type:

```
df %>%
mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(case_when(is.na(.) ~ 0,TRUE ~ .)))
```

Answer (score 0):

you just do `dtf[,colnames(dtf) != "id"] <- NA` in one go... this will replace all column values except `id` with `NA`