# Replacing N/A with 0 when N/A is not a missing value

Tags: r

I have a data set with N/A appearing but the N/A means 0 so it isn't a missing value as such.  Specifically, where there is no garage the data is N/A.
I've followed the usual path to change to numeric, but it isn't working for me. I'm new to r so I have limited knowledge, but it's driving me nuts.
How should I deal with this issue?

Comment: Have you tried `mydata[is.na(mydata)] <- 0`

Comment: Please see my answer to see if this works or if you have any questions. In the future, it is better to include a reproducible example. It will make others easier to answer your question.

Comment: One of this link should work for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161836/how-do-i-replace-na-values-with-zeros-in-an-r-dataframe. If you have string "NA" use `mydata[mydata == 'NA'] <- 0` like in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036989/replace-all-0-values-to-na

Answer (score 0):

Here is one idea. We can use `ifelse` to replace a target value to `0`.

```
# Create an example data frame
dat <- data.frame(a = c("1", "5", "3", "N/A"),
                  b = c("a", "b", "c", "d"))

# Replace N/A with 0 in column a
dat$a <- ifelse(dat$a %in% "N/A", "0", dat$a)
# Convert column a to numeric
dat$a <- as.numeric(dat$a)

# See the results
dat
#   a b
# 1 1 a
# 2 5 b
# 3 3 c
# 4 0 d
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited my response to this question:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(stringr)

df <- tibble(x = c("1", "2", "N/A"), y = c("4", "N/A", "5"))

df %>%
  mutate(across(x:y, ~ str_replace(.x, "N/A", "0")), 
         across(x:y, ~ parse_double(.x))) 

# A tibble: 3 x 2
      x     y
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     4
2     2     0
3     0     5
```

Comment: The question specifies that the string "N/A" should be replaced by 0, not NA.

Comment: Oh sorry, that was a huge mistake. Thank you very much dear Mr. @neilfws for letting me know.