# Replacing Character "" With NA

Tags: r

I have a df where a bunch of missing data came in as empty character strings, so "" instead of NA or something useful.

I have tried to replace it with NA using this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036989/replace-all-0-values-to-na):

```
df[df == 0] <- NA
```

Which in mine is:

```
nc_allparcels[nc_allparcels == ""] <- NA
```

However, the error I get is:

Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) :
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Any suggestions for fixing this? Thanks!

Comment: Hard to solve an error, if you do not provide sample data to reproduce the error with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the function:

```
naniar::replace_with_na_all

A <- c("a", "b", "c", "")
B <- c(",", ".", "", "-")
df <- data.frame(A, B)

naniar::replace_with_na_all(data = df, condition = ~.x == "")
```

OR if just certain columns should be modified

```
naniar::replace_with_na_at(data = df, .vars = "A", condition = ~.x == "")
naniar::replace_with_na_at(data = df, .vars = c("A", "B"), condition = ~.x == "")
```

Comment: Hi, I gave this a go but it took too long to do the whole file (left it running overnight and was still going this morning).

I tried to speciffy it to the specific column that I cared about as: replace_with_na_all(data = df$column, condition = ~.x == ""), but that reduced all observations to 1. Am I doing  this wrong?