# Find and Replace number to NA in array R

Tags: r, arrays, for-loop, nifti

I have some NifTi files of brain images where there are lots of zeros that I want to replace with NAs but I'm not sure how to do it.  I read in the description of the `is.na()` function that: "the generic function is.na<- sets elements to NA" so I thought I could use that, but it didn't work. Here is specifically what I tried:

```
library(RNifti)

in.path <- "R_Things/Voxel/"
out.path <- "R_Things/Outputs/"

ids <- c('100','101','102','103','104')

for (i in ids) {

a <- readNifti(paste0(in.path, i, ".nii.gz"))

is.na(a) <- 0


writeNifti(image=a, file=paste0(out.path, i, "_with_NAs.nii.gz"))

}
```

Any thoughts on what I could do differently would be very helpful, thanks!

Comment: To replace zeros with NAs: `a[a==0] <- NA`

Comment: Possible duplicate - [Replace all 0 values to NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036989/replace-all-0-values-to-na)

Comment: Thank you @Baroque that did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, here was my final code thanks to @Baroque

```
library(RNifti)

in.path <- "R_Things/Voxel/"
out.path <- "R_Things/Outputs/"

ids <- c('100','101','102','103','104')

for (i in ids) {

a <- readNifti(paste0(in.path, i, ".nii.gz"))

a[a==0] <- NA

writeNifti(image=a, file=paste0(out.path, i, "_with_NAs.nii.gz"))

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possible option to replace `0` by `NA`

```
> replace(a, a == 0, NA)
[1] NA  1  2 NA  3 -1

> a * NA^(a == 0)
[1] NA  1  2 NA  3 -1
```

**Dummy Data**

```
> a <- c(0, 1, 2, 0, 3, -1)
```

Comment: The `a * NA^(a == 0)` is charming just for seeing a truth eval in an exponent.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasIsCoding but believe it or not neither of those worked.  I guess it might have to do with the fact that the data is in an array?