# Converting all and only suitable character columns to numeric in data.table

Tags: r, string, data.table, lapply, numeric

I have data as follows:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(panelID = sample(50,50),                                                    # Creates a panel ID
                      Country = c(rep("Albania",30),rep("Belarus",50), rep("Chilipepper",20)),       
                      some_NA = sample(0:5, 6),                                             
                      some_NA_factor = sample(0:5, 6),         
                      Group = c(rep(1,20),rep(2,20),rep(3,20),rep(4,20),rep(5,20)),
                      Time = rep(seq(as.Date("2010-01-03"), length=20, by="1 month") - 1,5),
                      wt = 15*round(runif(100)/10,2),
                      Income = round(rnorm(10,-5,5),2),
                      Happiness = sample(10,10),
                      Sex = round(rnorm(10,0.75,0.3),2),
                      Age = sample(100,100),
                      Educ = round(rnorm(10,0.75,0.3),2))           
DT [, uniqueID := .I]                                                                        # Creates a unique ID                                                                                # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036989/replace-all-0-values-to-na
DT$some_NA_factor <- factor(DT$some_NA_factor)
DT$Group <- as.character(DT$Group)
```

The last line converts the colum `Group` to a string. Now I would like to write a function that converts only strings  to numeric, that are suitable to be numbers, such as `Group`, but leaves `Country` alone because it has no numerical meaning.

How can I go about this?

Comment: (1) Your `data.table(.)` produces warnings about differing lengths, in general you should make sure recycling is doing what you want. Asking questions with working that is knowingly inconsistent in a sense that is outside of the issue itself is discouraged. (2) Is there a reason you're using non-`data.table`-native assignment (`<-`) instead of the intended and more-efficient `:=`? I'd think `DT[, uniqueID := .I][, some_NA_factor := factor(some_NA_factor)][, Group := as.character(Group)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought was to use `type.convert`, but that either converts `character` and `Date` to `factor`, or with `as.is=TRUE` it converts `factor` to `character`.

```r
str(DT[, lapply(.SD, type.convert)])
# Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':    100 obs. of  13 variables:
#  $ panelID       : int  4 39 1 34 23 43 14 18 33 21 ...
#  $ Country       : Factor w/ 3 levels "Albania","Belarus",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ some_NA       : int  0 2 4 1 5 3 0 2 4 1 ...
#  $ some_NA_factor: int  3 2 0 5 1 4 3 2 0 5 ...
#  $ Group         : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ Time          : Factor w/ 20 levels "2010-01-02","2010-02-02",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  $ wt            : num  0.15 0.3 0.15 0.9 1.35 1.2 1.2 0.75 0.6 1.2 ...
#  $ Income        : num  -4.4 -6.41 2.28 -3.85 -0.02 ...
#  $ Happiness     : int  3 10 6 9 5 7 4 1 2 8 ...
#  $ Sex           : num  0.61 1.18 0.55 0.69 0.63 0.65 0.67 0.9 0.7 0.6 ...
#  $ Age           : int  15 2 65 67 73 17 84 5 41 91 ...
#  $ Educ          : num  0.54 1.04 1.29 0.43 0.76 0.63 0.6 0.44 0.48 1.13 ...
#  $ uniqueID      : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
str(DT[, lapply(.SD, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)])
# Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':    100 obs. of  13 variables:
#  $ panelID       : int  4 39 1 34 23 43 14 18 33 21 ...
#  $ Country       : chr  "Albania" "Albania" "Albania" "Albania" ...
#  $ some_NA       : int  0 2 4 1 5 3 0 2 4 1 ...
#  $ some_NA_factor: int  3 2 0 5 1 4 3 2 0 5 ...
#  $ Group         : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ Time          : chr  "2010-01-02" "2010-02-02" "2010-03-02" "2010-04-02" ...
#  $ wt            : num  0.15 0.3 0.15 0.9 1.35 1.2 1.2 0.75 0.6 1.2 ...
#  $ Income        : num  -4.4 -6.41 2.28 -3.85 -0.02 ...
#  $ Happiness     : int  3 10 6 9 5 7 4 1 2 8 ...
#  $ Sex           : num  0.61 1.18 0.55 0.69 0.63 0.65 0.67 0.9 0.7 0.6 ...
#  $ Age           : int  15 2 65 67 73 17 84 5 41 91 ...
#  $ Educ          : num  0.54 1.04 1.29 0.43 0.76 0.63 0.6 0.44 0.48 1.13 ...
#  $ uniqueID      : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

So I think we need our own function with similar intentions.

```r
mytype <- function(z) if (is.character(z) && all(grepl("^-?[\\d.]+(?:e-?\\d+)?$", z, perl = TRUE))) as.numeric(z) else z
str(DT[, lapply(.SD, mytype)])
# Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':    100 obs. of  13 variables:
#  $ panelID       : int  4 39 1 34 23 43 14 18 33 21 ...
#  $ Country       : chr  "Albania" "Albania" "Albania" "Albania" ...
#  $ some_NA       : int  0 2 4 1 5 3 0 2 4 1 ...
#  $ some_NA_factor: Factor w/ 6 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 4 3 1 6 2 5 4 3 1 6 ...
#  $ Group         : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ Time          : Date, format: "2010-01-02" "2010-02-02" "2010-03-02" ...
#  $ wt            : num  0.15 0.3 0.15 0.9 1.35 1.2 1.2 0.75 0.6 1.2 ...
#  $ Income        : num  -4.4 -6.41 2.28 -3.85 -0.02 ...
#  $ Happiness     : int  3 10 6 9 5 7 4 1 2 8 ...
#  $ Sex           : num  0.61 1.18 0.55 0.69 0.63 0.65 0.67 0.9 0.7 0.6 ...
#  $ Age           : int  15 2 65 67 73 17 84 5 41 91 ...
#  $ Educ          : num  0.54 1.04 1.29 0.43 0.76 0.63 0.6 0.44 0.48 1.13 ...
#  $ uniqueID      : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

With larger data, you may prefer to break the `grepl` condition out so that you define which columns to work on:

```r
mytypetest <- function(z) is.character(z) && all(grepl("^-?[\\d.]+(?:e-?\\d+)?$", z, perl = TRUE))
cols <- which(sapply(DT, mytypetest))
cols
# Group 
#     5 
DT[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = cols]
str(DT)
# Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':    100 obs. of  13 variables:
#  $ panelID       : int  4 39 1 34 23 43 14 18 33 21 ...
#  $ Country       : chr  "Albania" "Albania" "Albania" "Albania" ...
#  $ some_NA       : int  0 2 4 1 5 3 0 2 4 1 ...
#  $ some_NA_factor: Factor w/ 6 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 4 3 1 6 2 5 4 3 1 6 ...
#  $ Group         : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ Time          : Date, format: "2010-01-02" "2010-02-02" "2010-03-02" ...
#  $ wt            : num  0.15 0.3 0.15 0.9 1.35 1.2 1.2 0.75 0.6 1.2 ...
#  $ Income        : num  -4.4 -6.41 2.28 -3.85 -0.02 ...
#  $ Happiness     : int  3 10 6 9 5 7 4 1 2 8 ...
#  $ Sex           : num  0.61 1.18 0.55 0.69 0.63 0.65 0.67 0.9 0.7 0.6 ...
#  $ Age           : int  15 2 65 67 73 17 84 5 41 91 ...
#  $ Educ          : num  0.54 1.04 1.29 0.43 0.76 0.63 0.6 0.44 0.48 1.13 ...
#  $ uniqueID      : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

This last one will be technically faster with any sized data, but it might be noticeable for larger (columns and/or rows) data.