# R - replacing the zero values in *just one row* of a matrix with NA

Tags: r, matrix, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

Matrix `A` has some zeros and ones in its first row.

```
A <- matrix(data=c( 0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,  #1
                    0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,  #2
                    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  #3
                    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,  #4
                    0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,  #5
                    0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,  #6
                    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  #7
                    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  #8
                    0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0 ),#9
            nrow=9, ncol=9)
```

I need to replace the zeros in *only this row* with `NA` values. The `result` should look like this:

```
result <- matrix(data=c( NA,NA,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,  #1
                    0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,  #2
                    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  #3
                    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,  #4
                    0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,  #5
                    0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,  #6
                    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  #7
                    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  #8
                    0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0 ),#9
            nrow=9, ncol=9)
```

[Other solutions to similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036989/replace-all-0-values-to-na) that fully replace a given value in the entire matrix with another value do not apply, and I'm surprised that I haven't been able to extend these solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
A[1, A[1,] == 0] <- NA
A
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
#  [1,]   NA   NA    1    1   NA   NA   NA    1   NA
#  [2,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
#  [3,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#  [4,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
#  [5,]    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
#  [6,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
#  [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#  [8,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#  [9,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
```