# Substitute NA values based on second column

Tags: r, if-statement

really simple question here.
I need help writing a simple if_else statment.

I need a line of code that replaces NA in column A based on a condition met in column B

Sample code:

```html
A   B
1   3
4   2
7   5
10  5
```

for example, if cell incolumnn B=5, then fill NA in column A

Desired output:

```html
A   B
1   3
4   2
NA  5
NA  5
```

Comment: See also [Replace all 0 values to NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036989/replace-all-0-values-to-na)

Comment: If your data frame were called `df1`, you could use `df1$A = ifelse(df1$B == 5, NA, df1$A)`

Comment: Could also try `df[df$B == 5, “A”] <- NA`