# Replacing all missing values in R data.table with a value

Tags: r, data.table

If you have an R data.table that has missing values, how do you replace all of them with say, the value 0? E.g.

```
aa = data.table(V1=1:10,V2=c(1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4))
bb = data.table(V1=3:6,X=letters[1:4])
setkey(aa,V1)
setkey(bb,V1)
tt = bb[aa]

    V1  X V2
 1:  1 NA  1
 2:  2 NA  2
 3:  3  a  2
 4:  4  b  3
 5:  5  c  3
 6:  6  d  3
 7:  7 NA  4
 8:  8 NA  4
 9:  9 NA  4
10: 10 NA  4
```

Any way to do this in one line? If it were just a matrix, you could just do:

```
tt[is.na(tt)] = 0
```

Comment: `tt[is.na(tt)] = 0` works for me.

Comment: You're right, I don't know where I was looking. Feel free to answer I'll accept it.

Comment: +1 for the nice question. But the answer you've chosen is not the idiomatic way. I'd advice you to reconsider.

Comment: thinking of how I'd *want* this to work, `tt[is.na(tt), .SD := 0]` comes to mind

Comment: @eddi, Hm, that seems nice and probably not that hard to implement... will give it some thought.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`is.na` (being a primitive) has relatively very less overhead and is usually quite fast. So, you can just loop through the columns and use `set` to replace `NA with`0`.

Using `<-` to assign will result in a copy of *all* the columns and this is not the idiomatic way using `data.table`.

First I'll illustrate as to how to do it and then show how *slow* this can get on huge data (due to the copy):

### One way to do this efficiently:

```
for (i in seq_along(tt)) set(tt, i=which(is.na(tt[[i]])), j=i, value=0)
```

You'll get a warning here that "0" is being coerced to character to match the type of column. You can ignore it.

### Why shouldn't you use `<-` here:

```
# by reference - idiomatic way
set.seed(45)
tt <- data.table(matrix(sample(c(NA, rnorm(10)), 1e7*3, TRUE), ncol=3))
tracemem(tt)
# modifies value by reference - no copy
system.time({
for (i in seq_along(tt)) 
    set(tt, i=which(is.na(tt[[i]])), j=i, value=0)
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.284   0.083   0.386 

# by copy - NOT the idiomatic way
set.seed(45)
tt <- data.table(matrix(sample(c(NA, rnorm(10)), 1e7*3, TRUE), ncol=3))
tracemem(tt)
# makes copy
system.time({tt[is.na(tt)] <- 0})
# a bunch of "tracemem" output showing the copies being made
#   user  system elapsed 
#  4.110   0.976   5.187
```

Comment: Great answer. Not strictly required, but any way to do this without a for loop, e.g. using lapply? Or does that make copies of the columns too?

Comment: I'm not getting anywhere near the time increase that you are seeing, regardless of whether I use `tracemem(tt)` before each run the respective elapsed times are about 0.34 and 0.42. `<-` is slower, but nowhere near as slow as your benchmarks.

Comment: @thelatemail, I just checked again. It's 0.386 vs 5.05 sec.

Comment: did you generate tt again before to run system.time? The first one modifies it by reference...

Comment: I've been using `tt2 <- tt <- data.table(...` and running the first `for` code block on `tt` and the second `<-` code on `tt2`

Comment: Nope, won't work. The first line assignment won't make a copy. And the for-loop does things by reference on tt, so won't make a copy as well. But `tt2` points to the same memory and therefore will be changed by reference as well with all NAs replaced.

Comment: You have to regenerate tt from scratch before comparing the performance. I also observe similar speedups with Arun's answer.

Comment: Thanks @Arun! This solution was brilliant! The best one I found so far that worked without throwing an error on a date field.

Comment: @Arun The `data.table` help file states ":= is more powerful and flexible than `set`" which hasn't been my experience. Do you know whether for this particular example it is possible to use := instead?

Answer (score 15):

Nothing unusual here:

```
tt[is.na(tt)] = 0
```

..will work.

This is somewhat confusing however given that:

```
tt[is.na(tt)]
```

...currently returns:

> Error in `[.data.table`(tt, is.na(tt)) :    i is invalid type
>   (matrix). Perhaps in future a 2 column matrix could return a list of
>   elements of DT (in the spirit of A[B] in FAQ 2.14). Please let
>   datatable-help know if you'd like this, or add your comments to FR #1611.

Comment: Yes, I think what happened was that I tried it and got that error and was confused, didn't think of actually trying to set it to zero directly. Thanks!

Comment: this'd not be the idiomatic way as this'll make a copy of all the columns.

Comment: perfect. I stopped when I saw that error. Whodathunk an assignment would work after that...

Comment: I gather it is because data.table specific code is called when trying to do the selection, but general data.frame code is used when doing the replacement operation. Confusing, but this is a particularly fringe example.

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of `data.table` and `lapply`, namely:

```
tt[,lapply(.SD,function(kkk) ifelse(is.na(kkk),-666,kkk)),.SDcols=names(tt)]
```

yielding in:

```
V1    X V2
 1:  1 -666  1
 2:  2 -666  2
 3:  3    a  2
 4:  4    b  3
 5:  5    c  3
 6:  6    d  3
 7:  7 -666  4
 8:  8 -666  4
 9:  9 -666  4
10: 10 -666  4
```

Comment: That is quite slow because `ifelse()` updates all values. Using [Arun's benchmark code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20545629/3817004), it is 15 times slower than the loop using `set()`.

Answer (score 0):

The specific problem OP is posting could also be solved by

```
tt[is.na(X), X := 0]
```