# How does the expression dt[is.na(dt)]=0 work?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to replace `NA` cells by some value but only in one column. I found [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379081/how-to-replace-na-values-in-a-table-for-selected-columns-data-frame-data-tab) explaining how to proceed but I don't understand how it works.

`is.na(dt)` returns a data table tracing the original `dt` but replacing all the values by either `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on whether the original cell is `NA`. Now a datatable first parameters is supposed to accept a logical vector to select lines, not a whole datatable. And indeed `dt[is.na(dt)]` returns an error but `dt[is.na(dt)]=0` will replace all the `NA` values with `0`. Why does adding an `=0` suddenly makes this call work ? Is it a special feature or part of datatable design.

Comment: @akrun `is.na(dt)` with `dt` being a `data.table` returns a matrix `class(is.na(dt)) : matrix` tracing the original datatable whose cells have been replaced with booleans.

Comment: I get error in both cases i.e. `setDT(dt)[is.na(dt)] <- 0#
Error in setDT(dt)[is.na(dt)] <- 0 : could not find function "setDT<-"` using v.1.10.0

Comment: Relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535505/replacing-all-missing-values-in-r-data-table-with-a-value

Answer (score 2):

The expression would work if it is a `data.frame`

```
dt[is.na(dt)]
#[1] NA NA NA NA NA
```

But, in a `data.table`, the syntax is different and converting to logical matrix is inefficient and not recommended in `v1.10.0`

```
setDT(dt)[is.na(dt)]
```

> Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(dt), is.na(dt)) :    i is invalid type
>   (matrix). Perhaps in future a 2 column matrix could return a list of
>   elements of DT (in the spirit of A[B] in FAQ 2.14). Please let
>   datatable-help know if you'd like this, or add your

A better option is `set` which replaces in place without copying

```
for(j in seq_along(dt)) {
  set(dt, i = which(is.na(dt[[j]])), j = j, value = 0)
}   

dt
#    a b c
# 1: 1 0 2
# 2: 2 2 2
# 3: 2 1 1
# 4: 2 0 1
# 5: 0 1 2
# 6: 2 0 5
# 7: 1 1 4
# 8: 1 1 0
# 9: 2 1 5
#10: 2 1 1
```

Or another version is

```
setDT(dt)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), 0))]
```

#### data

```
dt <- structure(list(a = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
b = c(NA, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), c = c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, NA, 5L, 1L)), .Names = c("a", "b", 
"c"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: but why does `dt[i, j]` accept a matrix as `i` when `=0` is added, is this feature documented somewhere ? Usually `i` is a logical vector to select specific lines in `dt`

Comment: @ChiseledAbs The `is.na(dt)` is a logical matrix and not a vector

Comment: @ChiseledAbs  It just extracts a single value and not multiple values by what you showed `dt[cbind(c(1,3), c(1,2))]
#Error in `[.data.table`(dt, cbind(c(1, 3), c(1, 2))) : 
  i is invalid type (matrix). Perhaps in future a 2 column m`

Comment: exactly that's my point, `dt[cbind(c(1,3), c(1,2))]` yields and error but `dt[cbind(c(1,3), c(1,2))]=0` doesn't, I'm wondering how this works.

Comment: Your second example only doesn't work because there is no `setDT<-` function. It works just fine if you don't try to do it all in one step - `setDT(dt); dt[is.na(dt)] <- 0` Not that I recommend doing this as per the question I linked above.

Comment: I believe the second code ends up dispatching to `\`[<-.data.frame\`` as you can see by running `debug(\`[<-.data.frame\`)` before trying the assignment operation. Presumably because `data.table`s are also `data.frame`s