# Read in certain numbers as NA in R with `data.table::fread`

Tags: r, data.table, read.table

I am reading in some files created by another program. The program populates entries with missing values with the number `-99.9`.

I am speeding up some code from using base `read.table()` to `fread()` from the `data.table` package to read in these data files. I am able to use `na.strings=c(-99.9)` in `read.table`, but `fread` does not seem to accept numeric arguments for `na.strings`. The string counterpart, `na.strings=c("-99.9")`, does not work, and gives me the error: `'na.strings' is type '`.

Can I make `fread` read in the number `-99.9` as `NA`?

Comment: if you're comfortable with sed/awk you could do this on the commandline and substitute -99.9 with NA and then read the file in with fread

Comment: I checked if fread can take a colClasses arguement, turns out it from the documentation "All controls such as sep, colClasses and nrows are automatically detected. bit64::integer64 types are also detected and read directly without needing to read as character before converting." So your best bet is to do a sed substitute and then load the file(s) in R. This also might help http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~rpeng/docs/R-large-tables.html

Comment: @infominer I am aware of the `colClasses` argument, but I am afraid that I may not have prior knowledge about the column classes in the data files in the scripts. There are different types of files, and too many to hard code column classes for all of them. Will consider using sed/awk, or doing a post-processing and replacing -99.9 after reading in the files.

Comment: It's on the list to make `na.strings` work as you expected: [#2660](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2660&group_id=240&atid=975). I've added a link there back to here. Hopefully soon.

Answer (score -1):

If you read it in as `dt` change those values to NA afterwards.

```
dt[dt == -99.9] <- NA
```

problem solved?

Comment: Yes, but that won't be efficient. Use `set()` or `:=` like this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7249454/403310

Comment: Yes, this is what I ended up doing yesterday. I used a for loop with `set` over the columns to replace `-99.9` with `NA`s.