# Fast replace in data frame

Tags: r, performance, replace, dataframe

I need to replace `NA` in a data frame, the thing is that the table has many columns (over 5000), so the code:

```
y[is.na(y)]<-0
```

takes a lot of time. Is it any other way to do the same faster? With only 200 rows takes more than 3 minutes.

**EDIT**

The columns are all integers, and are the result of `dcast` (from the `reshape2` package).

I tried:

```
z<-data.table(y)
z[is.na(z)]<-0
```

and it still takes quite a long time.

Comment: How long is this taking? A simple assignment operation should be very quick. 5000 rows is really not large at all either.

Comment: @thelatemail, sorry columns

Comment: Ok - How many rows to go with the 5k columns?

Comment: @thelatemail 15000 rows

Comment: Did you try `data.table`?

Comment: Something strange is happening. I can do 5000 columns with 15000 rows using `y[is.na(y)]<-0` in 5 seconds. This is no supercomputer either.

Comment: @thelatemail, maybe, y is the result of a reshape2 function, but the class is still a data.frame

Comment: Are your columns all numeric? Try converting to a matrix and doing the NA replacement on that.

Comment: Here's what I did as a test, with 5000 columns and 200 rows: `test <- data.frame(replicate(5000,sample(c(1:3,NA),200,replace=TRUE),simplify=FALSE)); system.time(test[is.na(test)]<-0)` Timing = 1.6 seconds.

Comment: Have you tried `lapply`?  Also closing youtube and iTunes helps ;-)

Comment: @thelatemail. thanks. for me that takes for ever. and the laptop has 8gb ram and core i7.

Comment: I'm seeing BIG differences between R 3.0.2 (slooow) and 3.1.1 (fast) with @thelatemail's test code. Are you on 3.1.1 yet?

Comment: @Spacedman - 3.1.0 here.

Comment: @Spacedman, yes, I'm in 3.0.2. I'll change it and run it again.

Comment: `test[] <- lapply(test, function(x) replace(x,is.na(x),0) )` is also faster.

Comment: `m=as.matrix(test);m[is.na(m)]=0; test=data.frame(m)` is probably equivalent and runs fast in 3.0.2 too... I've always thought if you have a data frame as a rectangular set of numbers and *not* as records then you should probably be using a matrix...

Comment: @Spacedman; yes, that was fast. thanks both!

Comment: @thelatemail, with lapply is faster than the original but as.matrix is faster than both.

Comment: Your solution doesn't take advantage of `data.table` at all. You might want to check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7249454/2954547. In particular, read up on the `:=` operator and the `set` function.