# r: managing memory allocation in loops

Tags: r

First, this question is NOT about

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size n

I accept this error as a given and I am trying to avoid the error in code

- I have a dataset of 3000+ variables and 120000 cases
- All columns are numeric
- I need to reset NA with zero
- If I  reassign values to 0 for the entire dataset, I get the memory
  allocation error.
- So I am reassigning the values to zero one column at a time:`

  ```
  resetNA  <- function(results)
  {
     for (i in 1:ncol(results))
     {
            if(i>10)
            {
                    results[,i][is.na(results[,i])] <- 0
            }
     }
      print(head(results))
  }
  ```

After about 1000 columns, I still get the memory allocation error.

Now, this seems strange to me. Somehow memory allocation is incrementing after each loop. However, I don't see why this would be the case.

Also, I tried calling garbage collection function after each loop, I still got the memory allocation error.

Can someone explain to me how I can manage the variables to avoid the incremental increase in memory allocation (after all, the data frame size has not changed).

Comment: split your data into lists, apply the function to the lists, then recombine

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. But can you explain why this loop causes incremental memory allocation?

Comment: also, please feel free to post the answer and I will upvote. I hate posting answers to my own questions, but hate leaving a question unanswered even more

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235657/fastest-way-to-replace-nas-in-a-large-data-table

Comment: Every assignment operation will create at a minimum of 2 copies of the entire object. sometimes garbage collection needs to be called explicitly: `?gc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments above, the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235657/fastest-way-to-replace-nas-in-a-large-data-table):
[Fastest way to replace NAs in a large data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235657/fastest-way-to-replace-nas-in-a-large-data-table)

I tried it and it works very well

Answer (score 0):

I have learned an important general principle about r memory usage.

[See this discussion.](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html)

Whereever possible avoid looping through a dataframe. Use lapply. This converts a dataframe to a list and then runs the relevant function on the list. It then returns a list. Convert the list back to a dataframe.

The following example recodes numeric frequencies to a categorical variable. It is fast and does not increase memory usage.

```
    list1<-lapply(mybigdataframe,function(x) ifelse( x>0,"Yes","No"))
    newdf1<-as.data.frame(list1)
```