# data.table in place replacement not working

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to replace NAs in non-numeric and logical columns using following code:

```
test_dt <- data.table(a = c("foo", "bar", "foo_bar"),
                      b = c(1.243, NA, 78454),
                      c = c(NA, NA, NA),
                      d = c(1.242345235, 2.3453255635, 475.253552352),
                      e = as.POSIXlt(c(NA, rep(Sys.time(), 2)), origin = as.POSIXlt(Sys.time(), "GMT"), tz = "GMT"),
                      f = c(T, F, NA),
                      g = as.Date(c(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date() - 5, NA)))

replaceNABlank <- function(DT, cols) {
  for (j in cols)
    set(DT,which(is.na(DT[[j]])) ,j, '')
  print(DT)
}

to_quote <- names(test_dt)[!(sapply(test_dt, class) %in% c('logical', 'numeric', 'integer'))]
options(useFancyQuotes = FALSE)

test_dt <- test_dt[, (to_quote) := lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols = to_quote]
test_dt1 <- replaceNABlank(test_dt, to_quote)
```

sample data is provided in code.

In output `print(DT)` prints correctly but `test_dt1` is `NULL`. I tried to adopt the solution for [Fastest way to replace NAs in a large data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235657/fastest-way-to-replace-nas-in-a-large-data-table) in my case but it doesn't seems to be working. Any explaination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is around your return value from your function. You use `print(DT)`, but if you want to assign the actual result you should return simply `DT`. So one method would be to change the function to be:

```
replaceNABlank <- function(DT, cols) {
  for (j in cols)
    set(DT,which(is.na(DT[[j]])) ,j, '')
  DT
}
```

However, since `data.table::set` updates columns by *reference* you might also consider doing something like:

```
test_dt[, (to_quote) := lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols = to_quote]
replaceNABlank(test_dt, to_quote)

test_dt
#         a         b  c          d                   e     f          g
#1:     foo     1.243 NA   1.242345                      TRUE 2018-05-09
#2:     bar        NA NA   2.345326 2066-09-15 06:43:38 FALSE 2018-05-04
#3: foo_bar 78454.000 NA 475.253552 2066-09-15 06:43:38    NA
```

Comment: @Frank you're right, it doesn't do anything when you're assigning a `print` return value. They could also change the function to return `DT` which would work with `<-`. I should really update my answer...

Comment: Ok. Even with `DT` on the last line, there is no reason to use `<-` on the last line. `DT = data.table(a = 1:2); DT2 <- set(DT, 2L, "a", 3L)` just leaves DT and DT2 referring to the same table `address(DT); address(DT2)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225098/understanding-exactly-when-a-data-table-is-a-reference-to-vs-a-copy-of-another

Comment: @Frank, I might be misunderstanding you but are you saying that you can change the function to remove the `DT` and then the OPs original code should work? I realize for the second method, there is not need to return `DT` from the function but thought it would be too cluttered to include a small variation of the function

Comment: I was just saying that I read "which would work with `<-`" as suggesting that `<-` makes sense after a modify-by-reference function (like `replaceNABlank`), but I don't think it does. Nah, I think it's good to have DT there / return it as you do, and consistent with `set`, `:=`, etc.

Comment: Ah yea you're right that was a dumb suggestion by me. Thanks for the help btw!