# Replace NaNs with NA

Tags: r, data.table

Assume the following datatable:

```
DT <- data.table(a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),b=c(NaN,NaN,NaN,4,5,6),c=c(NaN,3,3,3,NaN,NaN))
```

How can I replace all `NaN` values by `NA`, i.e. in each column? Looking for an elegant (short) way to do this, but I am also wondering if it is possible using `lapply`, like I tried below.

My approach so far:

```
DT[,lapply(SD,function(x){x[is.nan(x)] := NA}),.SDcols=c("a","b","c")]
```

Actual result of my code is:

> Error in `:=`(x[is.nan(x)], NA) : 
>     Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").

Comment: See end of Matt Dowle's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7249454/8583393 You would need `for(j in names(DT)) { set(DT, which(is.nan(DT[[j]])), j, NA) }`

Comment: @markus thanks, that's it. I didn't see this post before, thanks. Need to use a good old for loop with `set` it seems :)

Comment: Glad it worked. `set` is actually super fast so don't get 'blinded' by the loop.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do it easily using dplyr's mutate_all function.

```
DT <- DT %>% mutate_all(~ifelse(is.nan(.), NA, .))
print(DT)
#a  b  c
# 1 NA NA
# 2 NA  3
# 3 NA  3
# 4  4  3
# 5  5 NA
# 6  6 NA
```

The code above is equivalent to

```
DT %>% mutate_all(function(x) ifelse(is.nan(x), NA, x))
```

Here's one way to do it using data.table syntax. I'm not sure if there is a simpler way.

```
DT[, names(DT) := lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(is.nan(x), NA, x))]
```

EDIT: An alternative way to do this, as posted by markus in the comments beow.

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, is.nan(x), NA))]
```

Comment: thanks, but isn't that `dplyr` syntax? I'd like to stick to datatable if possible just for one operation.

Comment: I edited my response with a way to do it using data.table syntax. I mostly use dplyr, so I'm not sure if there's a simpler way to do it using data.table than the way I posted.

Comment: thanks, this new approach works, but I also want to point out to markus solution in the comments. I will accept it for your efforts and because it works.

Comment: @DavidRosenman The advantage of using `set` is that it does the replacement [by reference](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html). With your solution you'd need to do `DT <- DT[, ...]`. Also you could avoid `ifelse` and try `replace` instead `DT <- DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, is.nan(x), NA))]`. Best

Comment: `DT %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(is.nan(.), NA, .)))` is how you can do it with `across()` that [superseded](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html#:~:text=across()%20supersedes%20the%20family%20of%20%22scoped%20variants%22%20like%20summarise_at()%2C%20summarise_if()%2C%20and%20summarise_all().) `mutate_all()`

Comment: The `mutate_all` method changes `POSIXct` values to integers. I can't figure the `lapply` approaches because they give `Error: object '.SD' not found.`  Is there a working way to replace `NaN` with `NA` or `NULL` that doesn't change data types?

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
DT[DT == "NaN"] <- NA
```

This should ideally find all the `NaN` that you have and replace it with `NA`. If anyone knows a better way please let me know!

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, but my NaNs are not characters so your code does not work: Error in `[.data.table`(DT, DT == "NaN") :  i is invalid type (matrix)

Comment: In addition, NaN does not equate to true with any value, including with itself.  See `is.nan` for the proper test.  Otherwise, you have the right idea.