# Fast alternative to ifelse for replacing strings in data.table

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table

I have a large list of data.tables (~10m rows in total) that contain a number of string variants of NA, such as "N/A" or "Unknown". I would like to replace these observations with a missing value, for all of the columns in all of my data.tables.

A simplified example of the data is set out below:

```r
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(v1 = 1:4, v2 = c("yes", "no", "unknown", NA))
dt2 <- data.table(v1 = c("1", "2", "not applicable", "4"), v2 = c("yes", "yes", "n/a", "no"))
master_list <- list(dt1 = dt1, dt2 = dt2)
```

The following solution works, but it is taking a prohibitively long time (~30 minutes with the full data) so I am trying to find a more efficient solution:

```r
unknowns <- c("n/a", "not applicable", "unknown")
na_edit <- function(x){ifelse(x %in% unknowns, NA, x)}

master_list <- lapply(master_list, function(dt) {
 dt[, lapply(.SD, na_edit)]
})

> master_list$dt1
   v1   v2
1:  1  yes
2:  2   no
3:  3 <NA>
4:  4 <NA>
```

I have tried something resembling the following, removing the need for the `ifelse`, but I have not been able to make this work across multiple columns.

```r
lapply(master_list, function(dt) {
  dt[v2 %in% unknowns, v2 := NA]
})
```

I feel an answer may lie in the responses in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235657/fastest-way-to-replace-nas-in-a-large-data-table?rq=1). Would anyone be able to help me apply similar, or other methods, to the problem above? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: A better option would be to specify in `fread`, `na.strings` while reading (as it is a `data.table` input) or with `read.table/read.csv` instead of post-processing for conversion to missing values `NA`, It may be done by `lapply(files, fread, na.strings = c("n/a", "not applicable", "unknown"))`

Comment: @akrun Thanks. I agree it's one option. But I'm adding to the list of strings to replace, and would prefer not to need to return to the time-consuming data loading stage each time.

Comment: ok, last I checked `fread` reads it pretty fast

Comment: @rsco, is there any reason for keeping the data.tables in a list? otherwise, you can use `rbindlist(master_list)[v2 %chin% c("n/a", "not applicable", "unknown"), v2 := NA_character_][]`

Comment: @chinsoon12 I'm running quite a lot of data cleaning operations first that are specific to each data.table. And then will use `rbindlist` afterwards. Some of the cleaning relies on having recoded the variants of NA.

Comment: maybe rbindlist, recode and then data.table::split might be faster than what you are doing now