# User-written function to replace NA by 0 by for loop not working in r

Tags: r, function, for-loop, if-statement, data.table

[data.table]
I have written a function like this to replace NA to 0 if a column is numeric

```
fn.naremove <- function(data){ 
for (i in 1: length(data)){
if (class(data[[i]]) %in% c("numeric", "interger", "interger64")) {
  print(data[, names(data[, i]) := replace(data[, i], is.na(data[, i]), 0)])
} 
else {
 print(data)
}}}
```

I have a sample data table like below

```
dt1<- data.table(C1= c(1, 5, 14, NA, 54), C2= c(9, NA, NA, 3, 42), C3= c(9, 7, 42, 87, NA))
```

if I use `fn.naremove(dt1)`
it returns the error

```
Error in `[.data.table`(data, , i) : 
j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'i' is not found. 
Perhaps you intended DT[, ..i]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.
```

If I run the code with the actual column index, it runs smoothly and returns the result I wanted for column number 1:

```
dt1[, names(dt1[, 1]) := replace(dt1[, 1], is.na(dt1[, 1]), 0)]

  C1 C2 C3
1:  1  9  9
2:  5 NA  7
3: 14 NA 42
4:  0  3 87
5: 54 42 NA
```

Please tell me if I miss or did something wrong with my function.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why are you printing in your function?

Comment: I searched through stackoverflow and learned that if you want your code inside to work, you need to put print() to it. Cause you will see the result print out in R console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `replace`.

```
replace(dt1, is.na(dt1), 0)
#    C1 C2 C3
# 1:  1  9  9
# 2:  5  0  7
# 3: 14  0 42
# 4:  0  3 87
# 5: 54 42  0
```

There's a nice [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7249454/6574038) around that stays in the `data.table` universe and which we may expand to  account for specific classes.

```
dt1 <- cbind(dt1, x=c("a", NA))  ## add a categorcal variable

library(data.table)
classes <- c("numeric", "interger", "interger64")  ## define sp. classes

fun <- function(DT) {
  for (j in names(DT)) {
    set(DT, which(is.na(DT[[j]]) & class(DT[[j]]) %in% classes), j, 0)
  }
}

fun(dt1)
dt1
#    C1 C2 C3    x
# 1:  1  9  9    a
# 2:  5  0  7 <NA>
# 3: 14  0 42    a
# 4:  0  3 87 <NA>
# 5: 54 42  0    a
```

Only NA's of defined classes are replaced. This should be most effective since no copies are made.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Maybe I have to come back to manual way of filtering out categorical columns, it will be easier!

Comment: @1darknight See update which accounts for desired class selection.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `names(dt1[, 1])` works but when you do -

```
i <- 1
names(dt1[, i])
```

It doesn't work and returns an error

> Error in `[.data.table`(dt1, , i) :
> j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'i' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[, ..i]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.

The solution is to use `..i` i.e `names(dt1[, ..i])`.

---

Other option is -

```
fn.naremove <- function(data){ 
  for (i in 1: length(data)){
    if (class(data[[i]]) %in% c("numeric", "interger", "interger64")) {
      print(data[, names(data)[i] := replace(data[[i]], is.na(data[[i]]), 0)])
    } else {
      print(data)
    }}
}
fn.naremove(dt1)
```